# ASP.NET ajax do not work

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I do not know why this do not work(can not call SendValues method).There is no error raise up.
Can anyone help me ? Thank you very much!

The html page some thing like below:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $("#Button1").click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "WebForm1.aspx/SendValues",
                 data: { 'Code': '1026' },
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (json) {
                     alert(json.d);
                 },
                 failure: function () {
                     alert("Sorry,there is a error!");
                 }
             });

         });
     });
 </script>
```

The c# code Some thing like:

```
 public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SendValues(string Code)
    {
        string contects = string.Empty;

        return contects;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "dont work"?

Comment: @Kirill Bestemyanov can not call SendValues methond

Comment: Can you see if the AJAX request actually fires (using Fiddler or some other web proxy)? Do you see the function executing (using the developer tools on the browser)? Are you getting an exception on the server - if so what?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by chage data: { 'Code': '1026' } to "data: { 'Code': '1026' }"

Answer (score 0):

Data should be specified as,

```
data: '{ Code:["1026"]}'
```